# Strange behavior with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

First, this code works perfectly since today, I don't know why, this have changed, and I didn't modify it. This is the code:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res){

  var tags = req.body.tags.split(" ");

  usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

    console.log(user);

   var img = user.imagen.push({

     title: req.body.title,
     name: req.files.art.name,
     author: user.user,
     description: req.body.description,
     index: user.imagen.length + 1,
     path: './users/' + user.user + '/' + req.files.art.name,
     dowload: req.body.share,
     tags: tags

  });

    user.save(function (err, suser){

     if (err) throw err;


    fs.readFile(req.files.art.path, function(err, data){

       if (err) throw err;

       fs.writeFile(user.path + '/' + req.files.art.name, data, function(err){

             if(err) throw err;

             res.redirect('/home');

      }); 
     });
    });
  });
```

And when I checked an user, the imagen array of that user, looks like this '[object Object]'. Why this happens? Any solution for this...?

Thank's advance!

EDITED:

This is the Schema:

var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

```
  user: String,
  pass: String,
  imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              name: String,
              views: Number,
              type: String,
              author: String,
              tags: [String],
              description: String,
              index: Number,
              path: String,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
              dowload: String,
              like: Number,

           }],
```

});

Comment: What is your schema for `usermodel`?  It looks like `usermodel.imagen` is a String, so mongoose is casting that object for you.

Comment: There you got the Schema. `usermodel.imagen` is an array, and inside, yes there are strings, but `usermodel.imagen` is not an array.